# Why this highly oscillatory function is not Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am reading the following note:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3112v1.pdf

Please see Ch. 1.3 (p.6~p.7).

On p.7, it says the infimum is not attained with a control law $u(t)$ belonging to the space of Lebesgue integrable functions.

But for $t\in [0,1]$, $$\int_0^1 |u_k(t)| dt < \infty,$$ for $k\rightarrow \infty $. I am confused why $u(t)$ may not be Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: p.6-p.7 not available in the link.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Just fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed the link, but you should make your question self-contained. I'd do it for you if I wasn't about to go offline.

Comment: The limit function $u$ is integrable, however it is not a minimizer.

Comment: What do you mean when you refer to $u(t)$ in the last sentence?  You have not actually defined any function $u(t)$, nor does the text define one.

Comment: @EricWofsey The $u_k(t)$ represents $u(t)$ with different oscillation frequency, which is shown in the figure on p.6.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what $u(t)$ is.  How can you ask whether $u(t)$ is Lebesgue integrable if you have not even defined what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimizing sequence $u_k$ is bounded in $L^1$, oscillatory, which means that it converges weakly to the zero function. However, the functional is not weakly lower semi-continuous with respect to $u$, so in the limit the function $u$ is not a minimizer.

This shows that the infimum of the functional is zero. If there is $(x,u)$ such that the functional is zero, then necessarily $x\equiv 0$, $|u|\equiv 1$, a contradiction to $\dot x = u$.